# how to find array element is twice as other elements without using operators and maps or slice with o(n) and under 15 lines of code

Tags: algorithm, go

I have a question about coding. I thought to get some pointers from you on below question.
There is an array of integer numbers. Those array numbers indicate person age. Write a function to return true if there is a person who is exactly twice as old as any other person in the list, otherwise the function returns false.

Following are the constraints.

- Age is an integer with values that range from 0 to 50
- you may only use variables of numeric types (no array/slice/map)
- must have linear time complexity with just a single loop
- you may not use addition, subtraction, multiplication, division or modulo operators
- the function may not consist of more than 15 lines of code
- the function may not call other functions

I could come up with below function assuming list is sorted

// Go function: assumption, age list is sorted.

```
func isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers(person []Person) bool {
    if len(person) < 2 {
        fmt.Printf("Need minimum 2 person's age to continue\n")
        return false
    }
    seen := make(map[int]bool, 15)
    for index, _ := range person {
        if seen[person[index].Age] {
            return true
        }
        seen[person[index].Age*2] = true
    }
    return false
}
```

I am looking for help writing code using above listed constraints. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "you may not use addition, subtraction, multiplication, division or modulo operators". Screw that, I gonna learn welding.

Comment: A loophole: you may use a shift!

Comment: Can you please share sample code if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators.

As the ages are limited to maximal 50, there are only 25 distinct pairs where one is the double of the other: (0, 0), (1, 2), ... (25, 50). Each of these 25 possibilities could be a bit in a (32-bit) integer.

You could use one integer to flag with a bit that you have encountered an age between 0 and 25 (for the first part of the pair), and another integer to flag with a bit that you have encountered an *even* age: there you would first halve the age, and then set the corresponding bit.

When these two integers have a common bit set, the answer is positive. This is a logical AND.

There is one special case: the double of 0 is 0, so if we encounter a single 0, then both integers will have their first bit set to 1. But the requirement is that there is *"another"* person with the double age, so this would give a false positive. So, the solution is to treat 0 differently, and just count whether you have two of them.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers(persons) {
    let smalls = 0, halves = 0, numZeroes = 0;
    for (let age of persons) {
        if (age == 0) numZeroes++;
        if (age > 0 && age <= 25) smalls |= (1 << age);
        if (age > 0 && (age & 1) == 0) halves |= (1 << (age >> 1));
    }
    return numZeroes > 1 || (smalls & halves) != 0;
}

// Demo
let res;
res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([4, 9, 34, 12, 18, 37]);
console.log(res); // true

res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([4, 7, 34, 12, 18, 37]);
console.log(res); // false

res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([4, 0, 34, 12, 18, 37]);
console.log(res); // false

res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([4, 0, 34, 12, 18, 0]);
console.log(res); // true
```

NB: the number of lines of code is subjective in C-type and many other languages.

In Go it could look like this:

```golang
func isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers(person []int) bool {
    var smalls, halves, numZeroes int;
    for _, age := range person {
        if age == 0 {
            numZeroes++; 
        }
        if age > 0 && age < 26 {
            smalls |= (1 << age);
        }
        if age > 0 && (age & 1) == 0 {
            halves |= (1 << (age >> 1));
        }
    }
    return numZeroes > 1 || (smalls & halves) != 0;
}

func main() {
    res := isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([]int{4, 9, 34, 12, 18, 37});
    println(res); // true
    
    res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([]int{4, 7, 34, 12, 18, 37});
    println(res); // false

    res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([]int{4, 0, 34, 12, 18, 37});
    println(res); // false

    res = isPersonTwiceOldAsOthers([]int{4, 0, 34, 12, 18, 0});
    println(res); // true  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and great help. Iam going to convert it to golang and test it now.

Comment: I added a Go version to my answer. Could you tag your question with `golang`?

Comment: Thank you again. I tagged the question as go.